# Solr: using the labelled relationship for nested documents throws unknown field error

Tags: solr

Using the example document that Solr has:

```
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "title": "Solr adds block join support",
    "content_type": "parentDocument",
    "comments": [{
        "ID": "2",
        "content": "SolrCloud supports it too!"
      },
      {
        "ID": "3",
        "content": "New filter syntax"
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I try to index this json, it would give this error: `"ERROR: [doc=1] unknown field 'comments.ID'"` even though the field `ID` is defined in the schema (of course, `comments.ID` is not)

I am trying to use the labelled relationship and not the anonymous relationship using `_childDocuments_` because that is what the docs recommends. What am I missing?

Comment: I could add the documents without any issues...can you check if the schema is missing the _root_ field?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Yes it has the root field. I'm just going to flatten the json.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send this to the `/update/json/docs` convenience path, it will likely fail with a nested document.

Try instead to send your document to the `/update` path, and use the JSON command structure shown here https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#sending-json-update-commands

Basically, send to `/update` and wrap your document in an

```
{
   "add": {
       "doc": {<your document here>}    
    }
}
```

Be sure to also set the content type to `application/json`